# String pattern matching with regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying pattern matching expression for a below string. But it doesn't work. could you anybody help me on this ? Only Alphanumeric and underscore allowed inside,Both side
$ sign will be there. Ex strings: Test_1,23_test_2,test3.

```
        String text = "$test_1$";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("$([A-Za-z0-9_])$");


    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    m.matches();
    if (m.find()) {
      System.out.println("Matched: " + m.group(1));
    } else {
      System.out.println("No match.");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ is a regex meta character and should be escaped, try this

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\\$");
```

Comment: It is giving results as no Match.

Comment: The user has called m.matches() before the if else statement. Its because of this results are not coming.

Answer (score 3):

Your regex should be:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\$[A-Za-z0-9_]*\\$)");
```

Comment: It is giving compile time error.

Comment: Sorry, double backslash...

Comment: thats ok but still it is not giving results. It is ouputting : No Match. The regex seems to be fine but still results are not as expected.

Comment: I got it . The user has called m.matches() before the if else statement. Its because of this results are not coming.

Comment: Yes, that's why I put brackets to capture a group.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do...

```
s.matches("\\$[a-zA-Z0-9_]*\\$")
```